# How to setup name based virtual host using yast in open suse?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, opensuse

Im trying to setup virtual host under open suse. Im in Yast->Http server, when i check "Determine Request Server by HTTP Headers" I got error message `To use name-based virtual you must designate the ip adress on the server(...)`
I did some googling and according to what i found i uncommmented the `NameVirtualHost *:80` line in `/etc/apache2/listen.conf` and restarted apache but it id not help. How can i setup it propely(maybe I should do it through yast without manually editing conf files but i can't find that option)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was occurring because I have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `listen.conf` and `example.com:80` in ServerName but they must be exactly the same.

PS it's still not working as expected when I set `NameVirtualHost example.com:80` and then try to add server with ServerName example.com:80 I still get mentioned error message. Of course I got example.com in my hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Aha, yes that is true. I assumed you had that since you followed a tutorial. Great you found it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Quite outdated question but in case someone encounters it:

1) I added

```
NameVirtualHost my_virtual_hostname_here.tld:80
```

before `<VirtualHost ...` section

2) changed
`<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost my_virtual_hostname_here.tld>`

That did the trick for me. Of course as mentioned @Lord_JABA don't forget to add `127.0.0.1 my_virtual_hostname_here.tld` to /etc/hosts